# Parse Query Constraint Contained In Not Returning Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to run this query however it is returning no objects. Any help?

```
    for (int arrayIndex=0; arrayIndex<[self.cards count]; arrayIndex++)
{
    NSString *senderId = [[deck objectAtIndex:arrayIndex]objectForKey:@"SenderId"];
    [list_of_sender_ids addObject:senderId];
}
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"facebook_id" containedIn:list_of_sender_ids];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things that could be going wrong right off the bat: 
First of all, to query the user class, you shouldn't use

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
```

But instead,

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

Assuming your User class still returns PFUser objects. 
Another thing to make sure is right is the `@"Facebook_id"` key, and confirm in Parse that this is a  top level key that you can see on your Parse User objects. 
Lastly, make sure `@"SenderId"` is also the right key on the objects in `deck`, since you seem not to be querying based on the same key that could cause the issue.

Comment: @"facebook_id" is the correct key name (column name) in my User table and @SenderId is a the right key on the deck object. However wouldn't the problem be that all the fields under the facebook_id column in the users table arent being checked accordingly with the array of sender_ids?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but if those are the correct keys, then according to https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:containedIn: this should work. Did you try changing to a `[PFUser query]`?

Comment: YES i just tested it again after changing it to [PFUser query] and it works! Thank you! Would you mind explaining why that was the issue?

Comment: Parse is pretty picky about it's queries, and the User class is somewhat special. From what I understand, this is just the way to generate a query on that special class.